# Getting a field value from a field via a ForeignKey widget in reverse with django-import-export

Tags: django, django-import-export

I have it almost working.

Models:

```
class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('project.Parent')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Parent(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Resource:

```
class ParentResource(resources.ModelResource):
    children = fields.Field(widget=widgets.ForeignKeyWidget(Parent))

    class Meta:
        model = Parent
        use_transactions = True
        fields = ('text', 'children__child__name')
```

Then the view calls the resource and downloads it. The issue is, name is blank. So, everything else works just fine, but I can't get child.name to show up. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, [`widgets.ForeignKeyWidget`](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_widgets.html#import_export.widgets.ForeignKeyWidget) is used by **modelA** to look up a related **modelB** that *is* a ForeignKey of **modelA**.

I.e. a `ChildResource` can use `widgets.ForeignKeyWidget` to look up a `Parent`, but not vice versa.

Doing it in reverse, i.e. to loop up and/or display some fields of a set of `Childs` (who has a **ForeignKey** `Parent`) from a `ParentResource`, you need to do something like this:

```
from import_export import fields, resources
from .models import Parent


class ParentResource(resources.ModelResource):

    children = fields.Field()

    class Meta:
        model = Parent
        use_transactions = True
        fields = ('text', 'children')

    def dehydrate_children(self, parent):
        children = list(parent.child_set.all())
        return ','.join([child.name for child in children])
```

Using the [`dehydrate()`](http://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#advanced-data-manipulation) method. Then when you export `ParentResource`, you'll get a dataset object with a "children" key whose value is a comma-separated list of the names of its children.

Comment: But how to do it when you also want to import the data?